# Import schema into Samba/AD domain?

Tags: samba, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have [set up](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_samba-ad-dc) a Samba4 domain controller to serve as my Active Directory PDC. It works flawlessly in that respect. My next challenge is to install FusionDirectory to make managing it easier and to hopefully eliminate my Windows box that has the MS AD management tools on it. However, FusionDirectory requires that I install some [OpenLDAP Schemas](https://documentation.fusiondirectory.org/en/documentation/admin_installation/schema_installation) in order for it to work.

I have done some extensive searching, but have been unable to find any guides on how to import OpenLDAP Schemas into a Samba/AD server. Would someone be so kind as to explain how this is done?

Comment: [This Samba wiki page](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_schema_extensions) looks somewhat relevant. Does that help at all?